# Trying to understand the definition of purely inseparable element

Tags: abstract-algebra

i'm doing a seminar about Galois Theory but I have a problem with the definition of purely inseparable element and the one of purely inseparable extension, I read the definitions but i would like to see an example for each one of them. If somebody can help me please.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)\le \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ would be an example of a purely inseperable extension. Moreover, $t$ is purely inseperable over $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, any field extension in characteristic 0 is separable so you have to look for examples in positive characteristic. That being said, let $p\geq 2$ be a prime and $F$ a field of characteristic $p$. An extension $L/F$ is purely inseparable if for each $\alpha \in L$ there exists an integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha^{p^n}\in K$. Now consider the field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(T)/\mathbb{F}_p(T^p)$. Any element of  $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ raised to the power $p$ falls into  $\mathbb{F}_p(T^p)$ which means that the extension is purely inseparable.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing mysterious : If $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$ and $a \in k$ then $x^p-a = (x-b)^p$ where $b$ is a root in $\overline{k}$, so we can call $b= a^{1/p}$, either $a^{1/p} \in k$ ie. $a \in k^p$, or $k(a^{1/p})/k$ is a purely inseparable extension of degree $p$. Every purely inseparable finite extension is of this form $k(a_1^{1/p^{e_1}},\ldots,a_n^{1/p^{e_n}})/k$.

If $f\in k[x]$ is irreducible but not separable, since $\gcd(f,f')$ divides $f$, then $f' = 0$ so $f = g(x^p)$.

For $c\in \overline{k}$ with $p^e$ the multiplicity of $c$ in its $k$-minimal polynomial then $c^{p^e}$ is separable over $k$ so any finite extension is of the form $L/F/k$ with $F/k$ separable and $L/F$ purely inseparable.